# Calling main methods in other objects in Scala

Tags: scala, program-entry-point

Is it possible to call a main method in one object from a main method in another? I have the following classes and was wondering how to call two separate main methods within one program run:

```scala
object MongoUpload {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    .. upload to Mongo ..
    // Want to upload to Oracle here
  }
}

object OracleUpload {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    .. upload to Oracle
  }
}
```

Does anything make `main` unique among methods? Can I just call one from another?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### You sure can. Just like any other method, main can be called between objects.

```scala
object foo {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("qux")
  }
}

object bar {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("baz")
    foo.main(null)
  }
}
```

Running `main` in `bar` gives the following output:

```
baz
qux
```

The same can also be replicated to main methods with arguments, as in the following example:

```scala
object foo {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(args(0) + " " + args(1))
  }
}

object bar {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    ... some processing ...
    foo.main(Array["Hello", "World"])
  }
}
```

Running `main` in `bar` gives the following output:

```
Hello World
```

Whether or not it leads to clear and readable code is another question :)